# Carriage return Java

Tags: java, carriage-return

is there any way to print a line in java and then go back to the beginning of that line, i tried using \r however this only prints a new line and does not go back to the original line.

So basically if the user inputs "Hello this is lol"

I want to print all the a's in the sentence (none), all the b's, etc...
eg.)" e           "
then"He           " --> this however must be on the same line as above and you must be able to see the change.

Is there any way to do this in java?

Comment: This is a function of the console you're using, and not Java per se.  You can do it with GUI facilities, but generally not with the OS console.

Comment: so can it not be done in java alone?

Comment: Start it from the command line and `\r` should work as expected. Notice than `println` is of course out of the question, and without it you must be careful to use `out.flush()`.

Comment: why can i not use s.o.p?

Comment: You can use s.o.p as long as p stands for `print` and not `println`! The reason should be quite obvious: `println` prints a **line** of text, terminated automatically by the platform-specific newline sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a java question, but has more to do with the behavior of your terminal/console.

You are sending the correct character to return to the beginning of the line '\r' but it sounds like your console is not handling this correctly.

You should also be using the `print()` and not `println()`  function (or whatever the methods are called on the specific object you are using to write). The `println()` function will add a '\n' character which will cause a new line to appear.

Comment: so if i do this: System.out.print("A \r "); what would happen?

Comment: it should print "A ", then return to the beginning of the line and print " ". leaving you with "  ". (the comments seem to collapse some whitespace characters.)

Comment: this just prints it on a new line

Comment: Eg.) Hello there will give
Hello(new line)
there

Comment: @faraday, then this issue with with your console. Can you post your OS and console details in your question.

Comment: @ColinD - OP indicated on another comment that they're running from an IDE, not from the Console, which is probably the problem.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I ran this on my Mac, which is a FreeBSD underneath:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello there\rWho's");
}
```

It printed out

```
Who's there
```

If you are running this on Windows, then I cannot be sure what they'll do, but all *nixes should behave as posted.

Comment: Windows 7 prints "Who's there" as well. It just takes a very long time to do so. (Much thinking is apparently involved in `\r`....)

Comment: mine prints hello there (new line) who;s

Comment: Well, faraday, why don't you give us the relevant info: what platform, what exactly terminal, what exactly command on that terminal. Maybe something pops out.

Comment: Im using windows 7, jgrasp, and this is my exact code:   System.out.println("Hello there\rWho's");

Comment: As said, don't run this from any IDE. The IDE consoles are very much bare-bones. Run it from the command line using the `java` command.

Comment: Putting it mildly, that's an odd question, but it may clear up what your issue is. Start from here: [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "print a line". If you're talking about the command line of an OS window, then you're going to nee to about output terminal control characters to control the cursor.

It depends very much on which operating system you are using, but there are libraries output that can make it simpler.

You might be able to output the backspace character `\b` to erase the current line, but it may not work.

Comment: how would i use this instead of System.out.prinltn(data)?